# Withdrawal of support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

IBM bluemix team announced that they will be removing TLS1.0,1.1 support.
They have also said if we can access our applications with parameter 'alt' in our url , then we are fine. Does that mean we can keep using the same urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same URLs. Adding `alt` after your application subdomain just enforces TLS 1.2, and if you can connect you will not be affected by the change.
If, however, you can't connect using your current client, you will need to upgrade/change to a TLS 1.2 supporting one or you will be impacted by the change.